# JS reacts differently by calling or not calling a function (google maps api is used)

Tags: javascript, function, google-maps

I experienced strange behaviour by calling or not calling a separate function in JavaScript code. I am not able to comprehend the difference in result – from my point of view the exact same result should appear.

The following code is the working one. It sets the InfoWindow onto the markers and the links.

```
for (loc in alleDaten) {
        place = alleDaten[loc];
        place['marker'] = new google.maps.Marker({position:place.pos, icon:'marker2.png'});
        place.marker.setMap(map);
        doEverything(place);
    }
    function doEverything(place) {
        google.maps.event.addListener(place.marker, 'click', function() {setInfowindow(place.text, place.marker);});
        $(place.link).click(function() {setInfowindow(place.text, place.marker);});
    }
    function setInfowindow(text, marker) {
        infowindow.setContent(text); 
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
    }
```

The following code is almost the same, only the function call is removed. But the result is different: only the last entry of alleDaten is set to all markers and all links.

```
for (loc in alleDaten) {
    place = alleDaten[loc];
    place['marker'] = new google.maps.Marker({position:place.pos, icon:'marker2.png'});
    place.marker.setMap(map);
    google.maps.event.addListener(place.marker, 'click', function() {setInfowindow(place.text, place.marker);});
    $(place.link).click(function() {setInfowindow(place.text, place.marker);});
}
function setInfowindow(text, marker) {
    infowindow.setContent(text); 
    infowindow.open(map, marker);
}
```

Is there a reason for this behaviour?

Comment: Reason for this behaviour is JavaScript closure feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two work differently because you have async code that references a local variable `place` that is changed in the `for` loop before the async code runs in your second block of code.  When you pass the `place` variable to a function in the first block of code, that creates a closure that maintains that variable's value separately for each invocation of the function so the event handling callbacks will refer to the correct version of `place` in the first block of code.

Whereas, In your second block of code, the `place` variable that is referenced inside the two click handlers will have long since changed by the `for` loop before the click handler is called.

Remember, your `for` loop will run to completion (thus `place` will have the last value in it) before any of your click handler callbacks are actually called.  This same type of mistake is very common with a `for` loop index too.  The general solution is to create a closure that captures that changing variable for each separate path through the loop.  Passing it to a function as you've done in your first code block is one way to do that.